# How can I write neat code to get the last birthday date?

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-arithmetic

I know the day of birth, lets say: **1996-12-12**
I know that today is: **2014-11-12**

Now I want to get the date of the last birthday. And I have written this solution, but I don't like the complexity of the code. How can I write it more readable for other programmers?

```
$lstrBirthday       = '1996-12-12';
$lstrLastBirtday    = (strtotime(date('Y').date('-m-d', strtotime($lstrBirthday))) > strtotime('now')) ? (date('Y') - 1).date('-m-d', strtotime($lstrBirthday)) : date('Y').date('-m-d', strtotime($lstrBirthday));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its easier if you use the DateTime functions

```
$begin = new DateTime( '1996-12-12' );
$end = new DateTime();
$end = $end->modify( '-1 day' ); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

$bd = '';

foreach($daterange as $date){
    $bd = $date->format("Ymd");
}
```

**Edit:** So now you have the last entry ;)

Something like that i can't test it now but you can foreach over the period. If the date is in the past you should get the last birthday. If you make `+1 year` its in the future.

**Edit:** For @pascalvgemert perhaps its a bit more readable for you...

```
public function getLastBirthdate($startDate) {
    $begin = new DateTime( $startDate );
    $end = new DateTime();
    $end = $end->modify( '-1 day' ); 

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1Y');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    $bd = '';

    foreach($daterange as $date){
        $bd = $date->format("Ymd");
    }

    return $bd;
}

$lastBD = getLastBirthdate('1996-12-12');
```

Comment: But now I get all birthdays between today and the start date. And I think it's not readable enough for any other programmer.

Comment: @pascalvgemert Thats completly readable - if you don't think so, just write a comment :)

Comment: @pascalvgemert and you mean that your code is better for other programmers? I don't find that your code is really readable.

Comment: @pascalvgemert - I'm any other programmer. I find it extremely readable. In fact, if it were written using strtotime, like you showed in your question - I would find that extremely unreadable and a sign of bad programming.

Comment: No I don't think so, it says so in the question. I'm just trying to find the best readable option.

Comment: Ok, I will take back the comment about readability, because I agree the Date objects are far more readable then strtotime and I can't find any better solution.